# Why doesn't rxjs flow change after mapping?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is:

```
public events$: BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]>([]);
```

The data is requested and forwarded to `events$`:

```
this.load().subscribe((response) => {
      this.events$.next(response);
    });
```

There is a function that changes data in a stream:

```
public checkAll() {
    this.events$.pipe(
      map((events: IEvent[]) => {
        return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
          event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
          return event;
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

Why, if you subscribe to events $, nothing changes after calling the checkAll () function

As it seems to me, you need to do `this.events $ = this.events $ .pipe () ...` or forward the mapped object: `this.events $ .next (mapped)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why, if you subscribe to events$, nothing changes after calling the checkAll () function

you didn't save a reference to your mapping logic, or you could return the new observable you created inside `checkAll`

```
public checkAll() {
  return this.events$.pipe(
  map((events: IEvent[]) => {
    return events.map((event: IEvent) => {
      event.checked_export = !event.checked_export;
      return event;
    });
  })
);
```

}

and then you can subscribe to your mapping logic with `this.checkAll().subscribe(()=>{})`

Comment: How to apply result to `events$` bacause I use it in temaplte events$ | async?

Comment: Yes, I can do this `this.checkAll().subscribe((res)=>{ this.events$.next(res)})` Is it correct to mutable initial object this.events$?